# Kotlin Firebase cloud messaging "MyFirebaseMessagingService not registered in Manifest"

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Firebase Cloud messaging on my App, using Kotlin.

In MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt I get the message "MyFirebaseMessagingService is not registered in the manifest,

Also, my app keeps stopping when built.

I have spend whole day searching for solution but haven't found one yet.

I tried adding several services but with no success.

(like: "MyFirebaseMessagingService"

".MyFirebaseMessagingService"

".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"

".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service
                android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>`
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.util.Log
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
    import android.app.NotificationManager
    import android.media.RingtoneManager
    import android.app.PendingIntent
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
    import com.example.recapp.MainActivity
    import com.example.recapp.R
    import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener
    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId


    class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService(){

        val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"

        override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
            Log.d("New_Token", token)
        }
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")

        override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
            Log.d(TAG, "Poruka: ${remoteMessage.from}")

            if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sadrzaj: ${remoteMessage.notification?.body}")
                sendNotification(remoteMessage)
            }
        }

    private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this@MyFirebaseMessagingService, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
            val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this@MyFirebaseMessagingService, "Notification")
                .setSmallIcon(com.example.recapp.R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Poruka")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.notification?.body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())

        }
        }
```

App builds with no errors, but keeps stopping when built.

Build gradle (myApp) is ok?:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Build gradle (app) is ok?:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: MyFirebaseMessagingService needs to be the full name of the service class, including the package.

Comment: Thank you Doug for your answer. Can you please clarify - what does full name look like in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the full name of your service. For example, if your service is in package `com.example` then it will be `com.example.MyFirebaseMessagingService`

```xml
<service
        android:name="com.example.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: I tried that, same thing, but now in AndroidManifest "com.example.MyFirebaseMessagingService" - MyFirebaseMessagingService is color red, and says Unresolved class. Even when I add it with Alt+Enter, it adds: <service android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService" />, but it still says in MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt that it is not registered in manifest.

Comment: could you provide the first line of your MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt? It should start from `package `

Comment: I don't have package in MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt, it just starts with bunch of imports as stated in the code above, I just added .kt file in my app>java>com.example.recapp folder

Comment: that's strange. Where this file is located in your project?

Comment: in folder app>java>com.example.recapp (recapp is name of app), in the same folder as MainActivity.

Comment: so you have to add `package com.example.recapp` in the top of your MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt file. Then you can use just `.MyFirebaseMessagingService` in your manifest

Comment: Yes! Thank you! solved that,
Now when I try to send push notification from firebase, on device it says "Failed to post notification on channel "Notification", do I need to adjust code in Notification.Builder?

Comment: Yes! Another success, i google'd the solution for channelID, thank you Andrei!

Answer (score 0):

this is my firebase depedencies in build.gradle level app :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
```

and in Manifest

```
   <service  
     android:name = "com.aplikasipdam.lampupanggungcirebon.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
     android:exported="false">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
```